# Analytic Function Problem Differentiation

Tags: calculus, analytic-functions

If
$$F(z)=\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{\alpha \choose k}z^k$$
We have to show that 
$$(1+z) F'(z)=\alpha F(z)$$

well to solve this I will first compute $F'$ and multiply it by $(1+z)$.
But I am getting stuck in computing $F'(z)$.

Comment: On the other hand, you could just look up the binomial expansion theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$ \binom{\alpha}{k} = \frac{\alpha(\alpha-1) \dotsm (\alpha-k+1)}{k!} = \frac{\alpha}{k} \frac{(\alpha-1) \dotsm (\alpha-k+1)}{(k-1)!} = \frac{\alpha}{k} \binom{\alpha-1}{k-1}, $$
so
$$ F'(z) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \binom{\alpha}{k} kx^{k-1} = \alpha\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \binom{\alpha-1}{k-1} x^{k-1} = \alpha\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{\alpha-1}{n} x^{n}. $$
Now multiply by $1+z$ and use Pascal's identity
$$ \binom{\alpha-1}{n}+\binom{\alpha-1}{n-1} = \binom{\alpha}{n} $$
to get to the result.

Comment: thanks a lot for the solution.